# Fragment Tab header/label size

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am sure it needs a simple flag but I am not finding the correct one, spent at least 2 hours to find a correct solution. Hope to get help from you guru's.
I am trying to create a two tab layout using fragmentActivity. I want to give 50% screen space to each tab. I am able to do that (see attached Screen shot) the next hurdle is I want the tab header e.g. Financial with black bkg should take 50% and Others with gary bkg to take remaining 50%.
[image]

I hope I am clear with my question.   :-)

```
attaching my xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#EFEFEF" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/financial"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:tag="@string/financial" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/other"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:tag="@string/others" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>


**The calling xml would be**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
    </ListView>

    <fragment
    class="com.......android.activity.AccountsTab"
        android:id="@+id/tabs_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

adding tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/tab_padding"
    android:weightSum="0.5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_default"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You mean, both tabs should be of same size?

Comment: @ Raghav yes and both should occupy available screen width. Also I want to set up icon to the left side of each tab. NOTE: Icon will have different action. I have added tab.xml in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this you can add as many tabs as you want.

[image]
Hope you want this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did it other way but I tried it and worked for me. I will mark as answered.